# iOS Speech Reset With Different Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

I have a current speech recognition capture that works nicely - you say what you would like, and it get's it. Fairly accurate too for what it's worth...

The **issue** I'm having is such:

- If I attempt to **change** languages after stopping and starting, it fails with the following errors

  ```
  2018-05-23 00:51:51.878921-0400 APP[1237:332833] Speech error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kAFAssistantErrorDomain error 209.)
  2018-05-23 00:51:51.922965-0400 APP[1237:332833] Speech error: Corrupt
  ```

**However**, if I stop recording and reset with the *original* language, it will work just fine. For instance, even starting with Korean, any time I stop, switch to... Korean... then press start again, it works. No matter how many times I do this process.

The issue is, continuing my example, if I switch to a **different** language, EVEN English, *after* starting with Korean, it gives me that error (which is contained in my `recognitionTaskWithRequest` FYI).

> It appears the starting language is irrelevant to whether it will
>   work, just as long as I choose a different language it fails, and when
>   I select the same starting language it works.

```
    // Note: self.inputLanguageIdentifier is changed when you select a new language.
    // I have tested to ensure this ID is correct each time.
    // I.E. Korean prints ko-KR, English of course en-US, etc.

    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:self.inputLanguageIdentifier]
    speechRecognizer = [[SFSpeechRecognizer alloc] initWithLocale:locale];

    speechRecognizer.delegate = self;


    recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];
    AVAudioInputNode *inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode;
    recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = YES;


    recognitionTask = [speechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        BOOL isFinal = NO;
        if (result && !userDidTapCancel) {
            // in the console.
            NSLog(@"RESULT:%@", result.bestTranscription.formattedString);
            [self updateTextForResult:result.bestTranscription.formattedString];
            isFinal = !result.isFinal;
        }
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Speech error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            [self stopListening];
        }
    }];
```

My `stopListening` is such:

```
- (void)stopListening {

    isListening = NO;

    [audioEngine stop];
    [recognitionRequest endAudio];
    [recognitionTask cancel];

}
```

#### UPDATE:

What I have found, is that upon resetting **twice** in a row (keeping the same *newly selected* language), the recording works as expected.

But as it stands I can't find a solution that allows it to work the *first* immediate time after changing languages... bizarre.

Comment: Try setting `recognitionTask = nil;` in `stopListening`.

Comment: Had that - made no difference. In fact I originally set *everything* to nil, makes no difference